Modify Background Notification to trigger at specific time after conditions are met
I’m developing a game that offers free gems every day. The app checks if the gems have been claimed, and if they haven’t, it displays a badge with a count of 1. Once the gems are claimed, the current date is stored in an array lastClaimDate to prevent the player from claiming gems again on the same day.
I want to send a notification if the gems have not been claimed yet. I attempted to do this using the sendNotification() function, which should display a notification banner at the top of the screen once the function canGemsBeClaimed would return true, but this did not trigger.
Because I couldn’t get this to work, I switched to trying a simpler approach: sending a notification at midnight using sendMidnightNotification(). The idea is that every morning, the user would see a notification that gems can be claimed, this works.
The final goal should be that the user gets a notification at 9 AM that gems can be claimed if he did not claim the gems between midnight and 9 AM and should only pop up  at that time.
My tries resulted in either no pop up at all, or it would always show despite if gems have been claimed before or not.
So what should I do to modify the code properly? I believe there might be some logic issues in the current code which I need to rework. I am not experienced with background tasks when the app is closed, therefore guidance would help. Thanks a lot!
Here’s the relevant code:
import SwiftUI
import BackgroundTasks
import UserNotifications


class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    @AppStorage("lastClaimDate") private var lastClaimDate: [String] = [""]
    
    private var currentDateString: String {
        let currentDate = Date()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate)
    }
    
    func canGemsBeClaimed() -> Bool {
        return !lastClaimDate.contains(currentDateString)
    }
    

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "ijouClaimGemsNotification", using: nil) { task in
            self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
        }
        
        sendMidnightNotification()
        
        // Request notification permission
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Notification permission error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        scheduleAppRefresh()
    }

    func scheduleAppRefresh() {
        let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "ijouClaimGemsNotification")
        request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60 * 60) // 60 seconds
        
        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        } catch {
            print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
        }
    }

    func handleAppRefresh(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
        scheduleAppRefresh()

        let queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 5

        let operation = BlockOperation {
            if self.canGemsBeClaimed() {
                self.sendNotification()
                self.setBadgeCount(1)
            } else {
                self.setBadgeCount(0)
            }
        }

        task.expirationHandler = {
            queue.cancelAllOperations()
        }

        operation.completionBlock = {
            task.setTaskCompleted(success: !operation.isCancelled)
        }

        queue.addOperation(operation)
    }
    
    func sendMidnightNotification() {
        // Create the notification content
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "New Gems Available"
        content.body = "New gems can be claimed."
        content.sound = .default
        content.badge = 1

        // Set up the trigger to fire at midnight
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.hour = 0 // Midnight (00:00)
        dateComponents.minute = 0
        
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

        // Create the request
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "MidnightGemsNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

        // Schedule the notification
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error scheduling notification: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    func sendNotification() {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Gems Available"
        content.body = "You can now claim new gems!"
        content.sound = .default
        content.badge = 1

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "GemsNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }

    func setBadgeCount(_ count: Int) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setBadgeCount(count, withCompletionHandler: { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to set badge count: \(error)")
            }
        })
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.banner, .sound, .badge])
    }
}

Any help on why the notification is not displaying would be greatly appreciated.

All you need to do is 1. determine at what time you want to prompt the user.  2.Schedule a notification for that time. 3. If the gems are claimed before that time, cancel the scheduled notification.

I tried this, but if the player then claims, there is also no notification for the day after when gems become available again. But thinking about it: I need to cancel the current notification when the gems are claimed and schedule a new notification for the next day at the same time? Or is it possible to keep the notification active and just cancel the next trigger?

You need to schedule a notification for each day. You can't use a repeating notification. You can schedule about 64 notifications at once and you can schedule the required notifications each time your app launches. If the user hasn't opened your app by the time the 64 notifications have been delivered then they probably aren't going to open it

i think I will remove this item for it will not be helpful for other users but one final question:
In the current way notifications work I cannot schedule a notification that runs a check in my app which returns true, then send out notification, otherwise dont send notification, correct?
like:
sendNotificationEveryDayAt9AM() {if canGemsBeClaimed {sendNotification()} else {print("noGemsAvailable)"}}
The function would need to run in the background when the app is offline, which seems to not really work, right?

That's correct. The system delivers the scheduled notification without running any code in your app at that time
